# Looking for specific datasets with demographic data in column format

Tags: data-request, api, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, data-format

I'm looking for government datasets on a wide variety of topics concerning the population of the country. Things like the crime rate, unemployment rate, level of educational attainment by different segments of the population, median income, etc. I would also like this for a large range of years and also on a national, state, and county level.

I know, I know this is a crazy dataset which is very ideal, and I will probably have to cobble it together from multiple other datasets. I've already gone through the FBI API, BLS API, and Census API. They range in quality, but they are interesting and have lots of data relevant to the task at end. At some point I suspect I may also have to move on from the APIs on these sites and start doing some manually downloading of files or create some sort of scraper.

Really though, what I'd like, and what I have not encountered yet is a data format where the demographics are included in column format. What do I mean by this?

Well... when I query the BLS API, I provide a specific variable ID, say I'm looking for the unemployment rate for Male 16-19 year olds. I get my result. It will have one column for the date, one column for the variable id, and one column for the value. IDEALLY, it would be AMAZING, if it also had a "sex" column and an "age" column. It would be so amazing to have a dataset like this! Instead of having to know what the specific variable ID was, I could just filter on whatever demographics it was I wanted.

Currently, I am building this "ideal" dataset by hand so to speak. It's very slow going. So I'm curious if anyone here knew of datasets formatted like I am talking about. I hope this was clear.